# Nginx + php5-fpm not displaying php errors but cli is showing errors

Tags: php, nginx, runtime-error, error-reporting

the php files are not displaying any errors on the page, just giving a blank page instead.
nginx error log is also empty so its not some fatal error with nginx.
the fpm conf file has errors enabled:

```
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_value[error_reporting] = E_ALL
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php5-fpm.log
catch_workers_output = yes
```

php.ini also has: `error_reporting = E_ALL`. 
nginx also has error logging enabled. the cli on ssh shows some errors with the same file:

> Notice: Undefined index: country in
>   /var/www/includes/classes/class.php on line 64 PHP Warning: 
>   include(/var/www/includes/lang/.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in /var/www/includes/classes/class.php on line 66

the php file also has:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

I've looked everywhere, tried everything, the errors just wont show.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that there was another php compiled on the server with apt-get.
I just had to run apt-get remove php5 and use the php.ini from the package I compiled manually.
Be sure to restart php5-fpm after making any changes to the php.ini file.